# NullPtr exception while getting country names and country codes in backoffice

Tags: intershop

After upgrading to Intershop CM 7.10.18.1, we are getting NullPtr exceptions while opening store detail page in backoffice.
ISML template for store details is EditStore_52.isml, which includes ISCountrySelectBox module, which futhermore calls getCountryNamesAndCodes() method.
That method fails with NullPtr exception because of underlined call which returns null.
[image: failing method]

We are wondering whether this is a bug and whether the intended code was supposed to be:

```
countriesMap.put(country.getId(), country.getDisplayName(currentLocale));
```

Please advise on workaround for this situation.
The following is a stack trace for exception.

[image: exception stack trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more convenient way (because editing xml import files is tedious) would be to replace the erroneous implementation using guice module override. In a nutshell:

- Copy paste the original implementation of class `com.intershop.component.region.internal.geoobject.LocalizedCountryNamesProviderImpl` into a class of your own in your custom cartridge. For example: I just created a class `AppSFLocalizedCountryNamesProviderImpl` in cartridge `app_sf_responsive` to test this.
- Adapt above method according to your needs
- Create an override module (See [Cookbook - Dependency Injection and ObjectGraphs](https://support.intershop.com/static/Cookbook---Dependency-Injection-and-ObjectGraphs.html)). Following my example the modules `configure` operation should look like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        bind(LocalizedCountryNamesProvider.class).to(AppSFLocalizedCountryNamesProviderImpl.class);
        bindProvider(com.intershop.component.foundation.capi.localization.LocalizedCountryNamesProvider.class)
        .to(AppSFLocalizedCountryNamesProviderImpl.class);
    }
```

- Publish your cartridge, Restart your server

Comment: Needless to say that his solution qualifies as HACK. If you do that and later forget about it, you will not gain from the fix that we will provide you.

Answer (score 3):

Intershop delivers address data which can be imported/export through `Operations` backoffice (e.g. Login at https://localhost:8443/INTERSHOP/web/WFS/SLDSystem using Organization `Operations`). Out of the box such address data looks like this:

```
<country>
   <id>DE</id>
   <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute dt:dt="string" name="displayName" xml:lang="de-DE">Deutschland</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute dt:dt="string" name="displayName" xml:lang="fr-FR">Allemagne</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute dt:dt="string" name="displayName" xml:lang="en-US">Germany</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
</country>
```

As you can see, it only contains `displayName` attribute values for de-DE, fr-FR and en-US. A possible workaround in your case would be to export data, include missing attribute values and import it again.

*Please note: The work to deliver a fix for this is already in progress. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.*

Comment: Thanks for the both answers, we managed to get by using a ISML template workaround, we will be waiting for the future fix

Comment: Nice. Though, you'll get the same issue with ICM management application on Address Details page of a customer/user.